# Why is there no need for wsdl in grails web service?

Tags: web-services, grails, wsdl

I have a project where we have developed the webservices using grails.

Here we have given the mapping in URLMappings.groovy and have controller and Services defined along with domain clasess.
When we get a request we generate an xml or json response based on the request.

Here we have not used any wsdl file.

Can anyone explain how this works in background and why we don't need a wsdl here?